# Magento: Display products with group prices

Tags: php, magento, collections

I need to display the products which have a group price.
What I have so far is this.

Firstly I load the products collection.

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
?>
```

Then, I simply check 2 things. If the user is logged in, and the customer group.

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
// Get group Id
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
//Get customer Group name
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
$var_customer_group = $group->getCode();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
}?>

<?php if ($var_customer_group == "Wholesale")
        { ?>
```

And I build a list with my products.

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
   <li>
   </li>
   <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
   <?php } ?>
```

How can I check in the `$_productCollection` which products have a group price.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I asked for. It's pretty simple actually if you start thinking outside of the box.
I will provide the code to help others with the same problem.

Firstly, add the collection of the products.

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
?>
```

Then,

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $product_id = $_product->getId();
          $arrayofproductsID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
          $groupPrices = $arrayofproductsID->getData('group_price');
    ?>
    <?php if(($groupPrices[0][price])) { ?> <-- //Here happens the check if there is a group price.
        <li> ... </li>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```